# Good practice for bug tracking github vs Company Customer Support

Tags: clients

- I have project `A` with MIT license and published in github (a.e. public)
- I have **private**  project `B` inside a company and we publish binary sources only.

For solving issues in private project `B` clients use company support team with tickets in Jira and so on.

However for Git project `A` clients open issues in Github.

My boss told me to redirect all github users to company customer support system so it looks like:

```
 Opened bug in Github:
 Bob: "I have problem to install your software"
 Me: "please contact out customer support..."
```

It looks bizarre to me, I think if project is public (like React,Mixpanel and so on), all issues and discussions should be written inside github project -> 'Issues' section. And to stay tuned, Customer support can copy all discussion and open ticket in internal bug tracking like Jira.

Who is right and why?

What is good practice in this case?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on Programmers not The Workplace.

Comment: You're both right. Your boss prefers that all bugs/usability issues be confidential. This is to create the illusion of perfect software. Apple does it that way. And you want to make sure that users can solve their own problems, especially if they run into the same problem that someone else had. Personally, I prefer your approach, but you do have to listen to your boss if he pays your salary. And don't worry, if the discussion of an issue is not hosted on your github, it will be hosted on some other forum that your company has no control over and that page will rank much higher on google.

Comment: But do try to turn off (or hiding) your bug tracker on github, and post the link to your customer support in a prominent location on your github, there is no point in you posting "please contact customer support.." one hundred times, nor is there any point in them posting the same problem twice (once on your github bug tracker and a second time with your customer support).

Answer (score 2):

I know why I would want all the tickets to go through customer support. First it makes it easier to see what is on any one person's plate when all the data is in the same place. It also makes it easier to prioritize work that has not yet been assigned or to see what will be affected if work is re-prioritized.

If the company plans to do any data analysis of things that are common problems, it helps to have them in the same place. And if you want to check support person performance and ticket response times, again it is simpler if the information is all in one place.

Answer (score 0):

It's the perception underneath that is being managed here.  I have seen really good customer write-ups of bugs and really awful ones.  Sadly most of the ones I see are awful...this depends on your clients though.

**Helpdesk**:
With the helpdesk involved this can often help articulate the bugs better and provide a voice to the help the customer is receiving.  I suspect this is the reason why this approach is being recommended.

**Github**:
Optionally the Github reporting allows interaction, but usually this is best with a technical client base who likes to get into technical input and feel involved in the development process.

So it really depends on your client base and the desired customer management appearance the company wants in which approach to take.  I'd recommend you talk to your Manager about it and why exactly that solution is desired and the end outcome that is hoped to be achieved.

Comment: Help desk generally helps getting to the actual issue instead of the normal "It broke...no I didn't do anything, it just broke" comments. Amen to people not being able to write good writeups.